# RealmSwift + Multiple Predicate

Tags: swift, filter, realm, predicate

I have no idea how to combine predicate based on user selection. Here is an overview of my data.

Person.swift

```
class Person: Object {

   let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var console = ""

   override static func primaryKey() -> String {
      return "id"
}
```

sample json data

```
{
 "id": 822,
 "name": "Ron",
 "console": "XBox"
},
{
 "id": 823,
 "name": "Jenny"
 "console": "Playstation 4"
}
```

say for example i have alot of data and console consist of either "XBox", "Playstation 4", "Wii", "Sega" or "PS Vita". I create a checkbox filtering option to allow user to selected the option they want to filter and show the name of the person who owns which console.

For example if they select both "XBox" and "Playstation 4" how do i predicate them both and show the result of the person name? Currently i can only show one option like this.

```
var player: Results<Person>!

func filter(sender: AnyObject) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.player = realm.objects(Person).filter("%K = %@", "console", "XBox")
}
```

Comment: You will need to create a compound statement in your query using OR here...

Comment: but if we do not know what the user will select how do we compound them?

Comment: the idea is to have as many sub expressions as there are options. And depending upon selected option compound the final query using OR. Please see a guidance answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You shouldn't dynamically craft an NSPredicate query string. It's much easier (and safer) to create an `NSCompoundPredicate` programmatically. You can pass `NSPredicate`s to Realm's [`RealmCollectionType.filter(...)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Protocols/RealmCollectionType.html#/s:FP10RealmSwift19RealmCollectionType6filteruRq_S0__Fq_FCSo11NSPredicateGCS_7Resultsqq_S0_7Element_) method. Here's an example to get all `Person`s who have either an Xbox or a Playstation 4:

```
// could use .AndPredicateType here too, depending on what you want
let query = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [NSPredicate(format: "console = 'Xbox'"), NSPredicate(format: "console = 'Playstation 4')])
let player = realm.objects(Person).filter(query)
```

Although in your case, you might be better off using an `IN` query if you want `OR` semantics:

```
let selectedConsoles = ["Xbox", "Playstation 4"]
let player = realm.objects(Person).filter("console IN %@", selectedConsoles)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! This is what i needed for the missing puzzle :)

Comment: how can I supposed to get the results rather than ["Xbox", "Playstation 4"] ?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

**Multiple Predicate**

combine predicates together with `NSCompoundPredicate:`

```
let predict = NSPredicate.init(format: "console == %@", "Xbox")
let predict2 = NSPredicate.init(format: "console == %@", "Playstation 4")
let query = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or, subpredicates: [predict,predict2])
let player = realm.objects(Person).filter(query)
```